# Assign MPI cpus-per-proc individually

Tags: parallel-processing, sh, mpi, openmp

I have a code that runs on **2** MPI process, each of them using multiple threads with OpenMP. My computer (Ubuntu) has **4** CPU (cores ?). Thus I made a small script to give **2** CPU per process such that each of them can run in parallel:

```
# Environment variables

export CPU_PER_PROC=2
export OMP_NUM_THREADS=${CPU_PER_PROC}
export OPTION="-map-by node:PE=${CPU_PER_PROC}"

mpiexec ${OPTION} -n 2 python3 main.py
```

But now I would like to give, for instance, **3** CPU to the process (rank) 0 and only **1** CPU to the rank 1 such that:

- Process 0 : use **3** CPU with X (certainly 3 for better performances) threads.
- Process 1 : use **1** CPU with Y (certainly 1) threads.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All MPI process inherit from the parent environment by default which contains the `OMP_NUM_THREADS` variable. To tweak the value regarding the rank, one solution is to change the environment variable in the child processes. In Python, you can do that using for example:

```py
import os
os.environ['OMP_NUM_THREADS'] = str(3)
```

This line must be execute *before the OpenMP initialization* (that is before the first execution of a `parallel` directive). You can tweak the right-end-side regarding the MPI rank.

An alternative solution is to use the `omp_set_num_threads` function call but this is not so simple from a Python code. Another solution is to use a `num_thread` clause in a parallel section, but again, this is generally an issue from a Python code. A last alternative is to calla shell script that changes the environment before calling the Python script but this script can hardly get the MPI rank (AFAIK there are shell variable to get this but they are dependent of the MPI implementation and so not portable).

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion ! I think the main part of my problem actually comes from `export OPTION="-map-by node:PE=${CPU_PER_PROC}"` that gives 2 CPU on each process, thus even if I manage to use 1 OpenMP thread `process 1`, it will still lock 2 CPU instead of only the one needed. Do you have an idea for this ?

Comment: AFAIK, the mapping operate at a node level and not at a core/PU level so it should be fine to use it here though you certainly need a more manual way to specify your mapping. The main problem is certainly the binding to cores/PU preventing 3 threads to run on 3 cores/PU (typically because the MPI implementation can bind the threads to the 2 core/PU in this case). If you use OpenMPI or a similar implementation I strongly advise you to read [this](https://www.open-mpi.org/doc/v4.0/man1/mpirun.1.php#sect12) and [that](https://www.open-mpi.org/doc/v4.0/man1/mpirun.1.php#sect13).

Comment: Note that the information of this page of the doc are very interesting overall. Note that each MPI implementation can have its own behaviour and the job scheduler can also play a role in the default settings since the MPI vendor implementation is generally tuned to be efficient on the target machine and so it should map threads to core automatically. On some machine, the default configuration is inefficient and on some rare others I even found bugs preventing a correct binding. Doing a manual mapping+binding is generally a good idea though it cause portability issues for running scripts.

Comment: Finally, if you are unsure about the mapping/binding, I strongly advise you to use the great `hwloc-ps` and `hwloc-ls` tools so to understand what is going on on the target machine. By the way, the "CPU" term is quite confusing as it can refer to both a core, a hardware thread or a microprocessor chip also called CPU. This term was used before multicore processors was mainstream. I think the term PU (processing unit) should be preferred nowadays (though legacy software still use the old term).